# php warning require error

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

I need to make a CRUD application with laravel, and i installed it just like how it is supposed too but now i get this error. I am just checking what version of laravel i have installed but somehow this shows up? i am no expert on any means. Can someone help.

> C:\Users\Gebruiker\blog>php artisan --version PHP Warning: 
>   require(C:\Users\Gebruiker\blog\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Users\Gebruiker\blog\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Warning:
>   require(C:\Users\Gebruiker\blog\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php):
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\Users\Gebruiker\blog\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17 PHP Fatal
>   error:  require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\Users\Gebruiker\blog\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\Users\Gebruiker\blog\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   'C:\Users\Gebruiker\blog\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\Users\Gebruiker\blog\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Comment: have you run `composer install`?

Comment: run `composer install`

Comment: thanks, i thought i already did that.

Answer (score 2):

When you first create a laravel project, there's a folder called `vendor` that laravel needs. Laravel the framework itself exists there among other folders there. There is a file named `autoload.php` that is `vendor` folder that loads all the packages that laravel uses. For you to get these packages, you'll run this command below

> composer install

then laravel can now work, so can `php artisan` command too.

Answer (score 0):

you have to update your wamp server, the php version has to be at least 5.7

Answer (score 0):

When starting any new Laravel project make sure you run `composer install`

Comment: Why is it necessary to run it?

Comment: To install Laravel and all the necessary dependencies. I answered him in the comments to the question, I only added the answer after so people could see it easier in the future.